# Compare two Lists for duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists:

```
    public static List<string> SalesAuthorityListFromFiles = new List<string>();

    public static List<(string UserName, string LegalCompany, string SalesAuthorities)> ListOfSalesAuthorities = new List<(string UserName, string LegalCompany, string SalesAuthorities)>();
```

I am trying to build a new list to get "Deleted Sales Authorities":

```
var SalesAuthorityThatNotMatch = SalesAuthorityListFromFiles.Where(x => !ListOfSalesAuthorities.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

I am getting an error pointing at `x` and I understand why, but I am not sure how I can fix it:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to '(string
> UserName, string LegalCompany, string SalesAuthorities)'

I need to join `string UserName, string LegalCompany, string SalesAuthorities` to one string in order to compare to `SalesAuthorityListFromFiles` values:

```
string.Format(@"{0} / {1} : {2}.00 €", UserName, LegalCompany, SalesAuthorities)
```

but how can I then perform the comparison to values in `SalesAuthorityListFromFiles`?

Comment: Little confused what your are trying to achive . Can you add a demo data in the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `Contains` to `Any` then you can format each tuple before comparing:

```
var salesAuthorityThatNotMatch = SalesAuthorityListFromFiles
    .Where(x => !ListOfSalesAuthorities
        .Any(y => $"{y.UserName} / {y.LegalCompany} : {y.SalesAuthorities}.00 €" == x))
    .ToList();
```

You could alternatively create a `HashSet<string>` of formatted tuples, which would use more memory, but increase the efficiency of your LINQ query:

```
var salesAuthoritiesFormatted = ListOfSalesAuthorities
    .Select(y => $"{y.UserName} / {y.LegalCompany} : {y.SalesAuthorities}.00 €")
    .ToHashSet();
```

Then `HashSet<string>.Contains` will work in `O(1)` time complexity:

```
var salesAuthorityThatNotMatch = SalesAuthorityListFromFiles
    .Where(x => !salesAuthoritiesFormatted.Contains(x))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you master! Programming is awesome, you will never stop learning :)

Comment: I am not a native English speaker. Can you please describe as well how it can consume more memory and increase efficiency at the same time?

Comment: Creating the hashset has O(n) complexity in time and memory, but every entry is only created once. The linq oneliner from above creates the entries multiple times worst case O(n^2) time complexity, but reuses the memory. with entry I mean that```$"{y.UserName} / {y.LegalCompany} : {y.SalesAuthorities}.00 €"```

Comment: The new `HashSet` will need to be stored in memory, but unless there are a *lot* of items, or memory is critical, it probably isn't worth worrying about. As for the efficiency, `Any` needs to iterate over the items every time, whereas `HashSet.Contains` uses `GetHashCode` to locate the item. As the number of items increases, `Any` will become increasingly slower, whereas the performance of `Contains` will remain fairly constant.